# What is "discount for validation"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I just read [this comic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/kidproof) in which one person says:

"And no discount for validation"

I understand each single word in that sentence, but the meaning itself is unclear. A discount is a reduction in price; a validation is the assurance of something;

Comment: <s>Impossible to tell what it means without any context</s>. I've now read the comic, and I still have no idea what it means.

Comment: It might be referring to "parking validation", meaning they won't validate his parking ticket so he doesn't get a discount. It's really poorly written and not clear.

Comment: Word for word, I'm with Colin Fine… and, no, validation is not "the assurance of something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign on the kitchen looks like a sign at the entrance to a parking lot.  Parking lots often charge an hourly rate and round to the nearest hour (so that parking for five minutes costs the same amount as parking for one hour).

Paid parking lots inside of malls, or otherwise attached to businesses often offer a deal wherein your parking fee is waived, or lowered if you can prove that you have spent money at one of the attached businesses.  This proof is referred to as "validation."

When I'm shopping at a store in a mall, I might ask the cashier, "Do you validate parking?"  If they do, they'll stamp my parking ticket, or give me a reciept or something that I can show the parking attendant to get the fee waived or discounted.